# Pagination for search results filtered

Tags: php, mysql

This is me again, I want to ask again, how to paginate the filtered results in php mysql?
My pagination displays only all files that is stored in database but when I want to search for example, all records of remarks interviewed, it will display all files having remarks interviewed, then in 2nd page it still displays the filtered results.

My problem is when I click the pagination, the second page will retrieve again all files that is stored in database. I want the second page is the filtered results.

Help me.

search.php

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="">
<br/>
    <div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <font color ="white" face ="Arial" size ="5" style="padding: 5px; text-align: center;">Search for an Applicant Record</font><br/><br/>
     <table border=1 cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=1 align ="left" >
       <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><font color ="white" size ="2" face ="Tahoma"><a href="search.php" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="/applicants/icons/reset.png" title="Reset Page"/><font color="white" size="2" face="Tahoma"><b>Reset</b></font></a></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><p><label for="searchfor"><font color ="white" size ="2" face ="Tahoma"><b>Search for:            </b></font></label></p></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" name="searchfor" class="tb5a" id="searchfor" size="25"  /></td>
                <td align="left">
                <select name="select" class="tb5a">
                <option selected="selected">Applicant's Name</option>
                <option>Position Applying For</option>
                <option>Work Experience</option>
                <option>Remarks</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><p><label for="from"><font color ="white" size ="2" face ="Tahoma"><b>Date Applied from:            </b></font></label></p></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input name="from" type="text" class="tb5a" id="from" size="10"  /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><p><label for="date_appliedto"><font color ="white" size ="2" face ="Tahoma"><b>        to:            </b></font></label></p></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input name="to" type="text" class="tb5a" id="to" size="10" /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="1" align="right"><p><input type="submit" name="search" class="update" id="button" value="    Search    " onclick=verify();/></p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'include/conn.inc.php';
//Include the PS_Pagination class
include('include/pspagination.php');
        //Connect to mysql db
        $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    if(!$conn) die("Failed to connect to database!");
    $status = mysql_select_db('timemanagement', $conn);
    if(!$status) die("Failed to select database!");



if ($_REQUEST["searchfor"]<>'') {
   $search_searchfor = " AND (lname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["searchfor"])."%' OR fname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["searchfor"])."%' OR mname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["searchfor"])."%' OR image LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["searchfor"])."%' OR appfor LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["searchfor"])."%' OR workexp LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["searchfor"])."%' OR remarks LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["searchfor"])."%')";
   }

    if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants_access WHERE date_applied >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND date_applied <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_searchfor;
    }
    else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants_access WHERE date_applied >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_searchfor;
    }
    else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants_access WHERE date_applied <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_searchfor;
    }
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants_access WHERE applicant_id>0".$search_searchfor;
    }
    if (($_REQUEST["select"])==($_REQUEST["searchfor"])){
        $sql = "Select * from applicants_access order by applicant_id desc";
    }
    $sql_result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo '<center>';
        /*
     * Create a PS_Pagination object
     *
     * $conn = MySQL connection object
     * $sql = SQl Query to paginate
     * 10 = Number of rows per page
     * 5 = Number of links
     * "param1=valu1&param2=value2" = You can append your own parameters to paginations links
     */
    $pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 20, 10, "param1=valu1&param2=value2");

    /*
     * Enable debugging if you want o view query errors
    */
    $pager->setDebug(true);

    /*
     * The paginate() function returns a mysql result set
     * or false if no rows are returned by the query
    */
    $rs = $pager->paginate();
    if(!$rs) die(mysql_error());
            if($sql_result){
?>
<br/>
<div align ="center">
<table id='table-2' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border=1 >
  <thead>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>Last Name</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>First Name</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>Middle Name</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>View Attachment</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>Contact Number</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>Position Applying For</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>Work Experience</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>Date Applied</b></font></center></th>
    <th><center><font color ="#640303"><b>Remarks</b></font></center></th>
</thead>

<?php

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

?>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["lname"]; ?></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["fname"]; ?></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["mname"]; ?></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><a href = 'view.php' target='_blank'>view</a></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["cnumber"]; ?></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["appfor"]; ?></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["workexp"]; ?></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["date_applied"]; ?></font></center></td>
        <td><center><font color = 'black'><?php echo $row["remarks"]; ?></font></center></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

<?php
}
}
else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="45">No results found.</td></tr>
<?php
}

?>    
</table>
</div>
<?php
        }
//Display the full navigation in one go
    //echo $pager->renderFullNav();

    //echo "<br />\n";

    /*
     * Or you can display the individual links for more
     * control over HTML rendering.
     *
    */
        //echo '<div class="pagination1">';


        echo '<div class="paginationTG">';
        echo '<ul>';
    //Display the link to first page: First
    echo $pager->renderFirst();

    //Display the link to previous page: <<
    echo $pager->renderPrev();
        echo'</span>';
    /*
     * Display page links: 1 2 3
     * $prefix = Will be prepended to the page link (optional)
     * $suffix = Will be appended to the page link (optional)
     *
    */

    echo $pager->renderNav('<li class="currentpage">', '</li>');

    //Display the link to next page: >>
    echo $pager->renderNext();

    //Display the link to last page: Last
    echo $pager->renderLast();
        echo '</div>' . '</ul>';
        echo '</center>';
?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

---

here's my pagination script.. 
pagination.php

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPSense Pagination Class
 *
 * PHP tutorials and scripts
 *
 * @package     PHPSense
 * @author      Jatinder Singh Thind
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006, Jatinder Singh Thind
 * @link        http://www.phpsense.com
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------


class PS_Pagination {
    var $php_self;
    var $rows_per_page = 20; //Number of records to display per page
    var $total_rows = 0; //Total number of rows returned by the query
    var $links_per_page = 10; //Number of links to display per page
    var $append = ""; //Paremeters to append to pagination links
    var $sql = "";
    var $debug = false;
    var $conn = false;
    var $page = 1;
    var $max_pages = 0;
    var $offset = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param resource $connection Mysql connection link
     * @param string $sql SQL query to paginate. Example : SELECT * FROM users
     * @param integer $rows_per_page Number of records to display per page. Defaults to 10
     * @param integer $links_per_page Number of links to display per page. Defaults to 5
     * @param string $append Parameters to be appended to pagination links
     */

    function PS_Pagination($connection, $sql, $rows_per_page = 20, $links_per_page = 10, $append = "") {
        $this->conn = $connection;
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $this->rows_per_page = (int)$rows_per_page;
        if (intval($links_per_page ) > 0) {
            $this->links_per_page = (int)$links_per_page;
        } else {
            $this->links_per_page = 10;
        }
        $this->append = $append;
        $this->php_self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        if (isset($_GET['page'] )) {
            $this->page = intval($_GET['page'] );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the SQL query and initializes internal variables
     *
     * @access public
     * @return resource
     */
    function paginate() {
        //Check for valid mysql connection
        if (! $this->conn || ! is_resource($this->conn )) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "MySQL connection missing<br />";
            return false;
        }

        //Find total number of rows
        $all_rs = @mysql_query($this->sql );
        if (! $all_rs) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "SQL query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
            return false;
        }
        $this->total_rows = mysql_num_rows($all_rs );
        @mysql_close($all_rs );

        //Return FALSE if no rows found
        if ($this->total_rows == 0) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "Query returned zero rows.";
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Max number of pages
        $this->max_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->rows_per_page );
        if ($this->links_per_page > $this->max_pages) {
            $this->links_per_page = $this->max_pages;
        }

        //Check the page value just in case someone is trying to input an aribitrary value
        if ($this->page > $this->max_pages || $this->page <= 0) {
            $this->page = 1;
        }

        //Calculate Offset
        $this->offset = $this->rows_per_page * ($this->page - 1);

        //Fetch the required result set
        $rs = @mysql_query($this->sql . " LIMIT {$this->offset}, {$this->rows_per_page}" );
        if (! $rs) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "Pagination query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
            return false;
        }
        return $rs;
    }

    /**
     * Display the link to the first page
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to 'First'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderFirst($tag = 'First') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page == 1) {
            return "$tag ";
        } else {
            return '<a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=1&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a> ';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the link to the last page
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to 'Last'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderLast($tag = 'Last') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page == $this->max_pages) {
            return $tag;
        } else {
            return ' <a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . $this->max_pages . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the next link
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to '>>'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderNext($tag = 'Next') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page < $this->max_pages) {
            return '<a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . ($this->page + 1) . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        } else {
            return $tag;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the previous link
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to '<<'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderPrev($tag = 'Previous') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page > 1) {
            return ' <a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . ($this->page - 1) . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        } else {
            return " $tag";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the page links
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    function renderNav($prefix = '<span>', $suffix = '</span>') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        $batch = ceil($this->page / $this->links_per_page );
        $end = $batch * $this->links_per_page;
        if ($end == $this->page) {
            //$end = $end + $this->links_per_page - 1;
        //$end = $end + ceil($this->links_per_page/2);
        }
        if ($end > $this->max_pages) {
            $end = $this->max_pages;
        }
        $start = $end - $this->links_per_page + 1;
        $links = '';

        for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i ++) {
            if ($i == $this->page) {
                $links .= $prefix . " $i " . $suffix;
            } else {
                $links .= ' ' . $prefix . '<a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . $i . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $i . '</a>' . $suffix . ' ';
            }
        }

        return $links;
    }

    /**
     * Display full pagination navigation
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    function renderFullNav() {
        return $this->renderFirst() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderPrev() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderNav() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderNext() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderLast();
    }

    /**
     * Set debug mode
     *
     * @access public
     * @param bool $debug Set to TRUE to enable debug messages
     * @return void
     */
    function setDebug($debug) {
        $this->debug = $debug;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use jquery pagination or limit the database records

Comment: Then pass the search key along with the pagination links...first show us the code,then will edit

Comment: hi.. I already update my post.. here's my other php script for pagination.. pagination.php

Comment: that means got some problem with your SQL query. 1st page is displaying result from query generated after search, and then if u click 2nd page, it will load the default query. to solve this problem, put the query after search into a session so u can use it in 2nd page.

Comment: hmm after my query for displaying all files? in here     $sql_result = mysql_query($sql);

Answer (score 0):

Add LIMIT offset,pagesize to your SELECT statement.

For more info on MySQL selects take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html